# How to get extension of file name within link

Tags: php

I've set of URLs each one ended with file name that has extension to its type

**Example**

```
$link = "http://www.some_site.com/test.vob";
```

Using `PHP` i wonder how can i get the extension of the last file name on the link so i wanna get `vob`.

I've tried this one but it gives the file name itself `test` but i want the extension `vob`

```
$filename = basename($link);
$filename = substr($filename, 0, strpos($filename, '.'));
echo $filename; // test
```

~ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$link = "http://www.some_site.com/test.vob";
echo pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // vob
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/oQn3c